# How to display debug register on the register panel of ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, register

Can someone know how to or a plugin that allows to display extra information, the debug registers (DR0->DR7) on the register panel of Ollydbg ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Using Olly 1.10, right click the registers panel and click "View debug registers":

[image]

You'll see them at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: That works, but i cannot modify them, especially the registers from DR0->DR3 corresponding to 4 hardware breakpoint. I see one time in a tutorial that shows the extra bar that allows modifying those data.

Comment: @SieuTruc to modify them, go to `Debug` -> `Hardware Breakpoints`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OllyDbg 2.01 exposes that via the UI by default, but you could write a plugin for it: [`Threadregisters(threadid)`](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/i_Threads.html)`->`[`dr[]`](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/t_reg.htm)

**Edit:**

See [AcidShout's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/10669/1562) for how to view the debug registers in OllyDbg 1.10.

Answer (score -1):

Highlight registers panel and click ESC on your keyboard.